# Adding an event handler on a createBottomTabNavigator of React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native app which main navigation is accomplished using a

> createBottomTabNavigator

as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

import HomeStack from './HomeStack'
import SettingsStack from './SettingsStack'

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
              <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
            )
        }
      },
    Settings: {
        screen: SettingsStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
              <Icon name="ios-settings" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
            )
        }
      }
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
```

As you can see, it basically includes two other components that are stack navigators themselves. I will not include them in order to have cleaner question. What I've added to my app is real-time push notifications as described [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications). Everything seems to be working fine until now but I have added the notification handler:

```
_handleNotification = (notification) => {
    this.setState({notification: notification});
  };
```

in my **HomeScreen** which is part of my **HomeStack** (The first screen). I don't really like this structure (having the handler in my HomeScreen). I have another screen (in the same HomeStack) that I'd like to handle this new coming notification. But I assume it is not gonna happen until this other screen is not mounted. So, I was wondering, is it possible to somehow define the handler on the level of the main **TabNavigator** and when handled just to redirect to my dedicated screen? I assume this is a bit cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to implement if you just create a custom Tab Bar component.

**TabBar config**

```
import CustomTabBar from '???';

const TabRoutes = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  Settings: {screen: SettingsRoutes}
},{
  tabBarComponent: CustomTabBar,
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
```

**CustomTabBar**

```
import CustomTabBarItem from '???';

class CustomTabBar extends React.Component {

  public constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notification: undefined
    };
  }

  render() {

    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const routes = navigation.state.routes;

    return (
      <View>
        {routes.map(route => {
          // Just some basic example, create a CustomTabBarItem according your own needs
          <CustomTabBarItem
            key={route.key}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.routeName)}
            routeName={route.routeName}
          />
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handleNotification = (notification) => {
    this.setState({notification: notification});
  }; 
}
```